# Linear optimization problem of $argmin$

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, optimization

Consider a vector $a \in R^n$.

I want to know how I can find analytically the solution of the following optimization problem: $x^* = argmin_{x \in R^n} f(x)$, where

- $f(x) = ||x-a||_{2}^2 + \lambda ||x||_1$
- $\lambda > 0$ and
- $||.||_p$ is the p-norm in $R^n$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question? are you asking for some optimization algorithm? pretty much any would do.

Comment: @anymous.asker my question is to find $x^*$. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the derivative, set it to zero, isolate x.

Comment: @anymous.asker thanks for your answer. The problem that I don' know how to derivate when we have norms.

Comment: @anymous.asker the problem I have $x \in R^n$ what should I do in this case, please?

Comment: @FouziTAKELAIT, a quick Google search leads to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482494/derivative-of-the-l-p-norm

Comment: @anymous.asker Your comment is not helpful at all. The OP is asking about an objective function with l1 norm, which is not differentiable. Clearly "take the derivative, set it to zero" won't work. And that's why people develops subgradient methods.

Comment: @anymous.asker That is right. (you may consider to post that as an answer). For the OP's question it's much easier to calculate this analytic solution than optimizing it with some algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the comments suggesting subgradient descent methods: the problem in the question does not contain any sum or similar terms, therefore the variables are independent of each other and there is a closed-form solution:
$$ x^* = 
\begin{cases}
    a - \frac{\lambda}{2},& \text{if } a > \frac{\lambda}{2}\\
    a + \frac{\lambda}{2},& \text{if } -a > \frac{\lambda}{2}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Could you detail the solution, please?